# 500 Vs 500.100 Error in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

When running classic ASP application in IIS7, when would a 500 error happen rather than a 500.100 error? What I mean is that a 500 error occurs but not a 500.100 error. I am under the impression that classic ASP would only throw 500.100 errors when error occurs in it's VBScript code.
Some explanation through an example would be very helpful.

Comment: I've never seen 1 500.100 error with ASP, only 500.

Comment: You are correct - I believe that IIS 7 just returns a 500 for any internal server error. Why is this an issue?

Comment: I have IIS 7.5 on my local machine. For classic ASP web site in IIS, I have specified a custom error page 'Error1.asp' for 500.100 error code. I used 'Error Pages' under website configuration in IIS for this. Now when an error occurs in a classic asp page, IIS renders Error1.asp. So that means error 500 is not getting raised. That is why I asked this question about 500 error Vs 500.100 error. Why didn't my IIS 7.5 raise a 500 error in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Classic ASP has always returned a `500.100` status if there is a script error. It's been like for a very long time in previous versions of IIS and the behaviour hasn't changed.

If you want to catch Classic ASP script errors *and* be able to read the `Server.GetLastError()` object in your custom error page (say for logging) you need to provide a handler specifically for `500.100`.

If you don't specify a custom `500.100` error then IIS will fall back to your custom (or its own) `500` error page but `Server.GetLastError()` won't provide any useful information about the error.

Comment: Kev - Thanks. Your explanation has been very helpful and made the difference between 500 and 500.100 errors very clear from a classic ASP perspective.

Comment: Yeah but let's face @OferZelig Kev's explanation is better. +1

Comment: It's also worth noting that IIS still has the built in `500-100.asp` that can be used to give detailed error messages for script errors. In IIS 7.5+ it can be found in `%systemdrive%\inetpub\custerr\<lang>\500-100.asp`.

Comment: @Lankymart - appreciated :)

Comment: @Lankymart but if a little research had been made before asking this question or answering it, you would have found my answer. And if you are smart enough  (you're a developer so you should be), my answer would be sufficient. And anyway, the correct way to avoid redundancies in questions is to mark a question as 'Already answered' or going to the original answer and edit and improve it. Because what's important is having one canonical question and answer, not to just gain points. Right?

Comment: Thing is @OferZelig I wasn't commenting here because I was looking for the answer, I already know it. I wanted a concise answer to link to for a OP who didn't know how to do it, Kev's answer fit the bill. I agree there should be one canonical answer but the way SO is designed I don't think that will ever be the case, so try to make the best answer you can in the meantime.

Comment: I have precisely the same problem, and the error in my vbscript is throwing a 500 not a 500.100, I can prove it because i configured custom pages for both 500 and 500.100 and it is the 500 that is executed.
I don't understand because as you say it it supposed to always throw a 500.100. Any hint why a 500 whitout the subcode 100 could be thrown ?

Comment: I just found out that the custom 500.100 error page is executed, but its output is not displayed, a default error 500 iis page is displayed instead...